How can I remove the vertical scroll bar in a table?
How can I remove the vertical scroll bar in a table on a WordPress site? Are there specific CSS properties or techniques I can use to prevent the table from displaying a scroll bar, while still ensuring that the content remains properly visible and accessible?

This site is for operating and managing websites - questions about coding/programming and web development are best asked over at Stack Overflow, or possibly on WordPress.

This is going to be an issue to do with your theme rather than WordPress.  The tables in core WordPress themes do not scroll as far as I am aware.
Tables that scroll horizontally are actually a better approach for mobile than not scrolling, as it prevents content ending up going one-word-per-line and being completely unreadable. I'm not sure why you'll have a vertical scrollbar, however.
In terms of your specific question, I assume your theme has an overflow-y property, which you'd need to override. It will be something like the following.
table {
 overflow-y: auto;
}

